Import PDF files from Outlook via Python
In order to download PDF files from the recent email sent by my colleague in outlook “colleague_email@example.com” via Python, I used this code to connect but I got an error even though my email address and password are correct:
import imaplib
import email
import os
# Set your Outlook IMAP server and login credentials
IMAP_SERVER = 'outlook.office365.com'
EMAIL = 'my_email@example.com'
PASSWORD = 'my_password'
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(IMAP_SERVER)
mail.login(EMAIL, PASSWORD)

And this is the error:
error: b'LOGIN failed.'

Any idea can help me, thank you!
